# markdown to html command (for an npm project build)

Tags: markdown

I have a markdown file that I'd like to generate into html using [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) on the command line (ie, as part of a build script).

The TOC in my markdown file mimics that generated by markdown-toc, ie - it looks like this:

```
<!-- toc -->
- [User Guide](#user-guide)
- [Configuration](#configuration)
<!-- tocstop -->

## user-guide
blah

# configuration
blah
```

When I add this to `test.md` and run the following:

`remarkable test.md >test.html`

I get this:

[image]

ie, the TOC is not being rendered by remarkable.

Can anyone advise?  I'm simply looking for those links to go directly the various sections in the rendered html.

Comment: Just a guess, but you may have encountered a bug. I suspect the HTML comments are confusing the parser. Try adding a blank line between the TOC and the comments. If that doesn't resolve your problem, please edit your question to include the HTML generated by the parser. schreenshots are not helpful when debugging Markdown issues.  You may need to use your browser's "view source" feature to get the HTML.

Comment: That didn't work either (I tried it first without).  Without the comments, the TOC generated but the links didn't work.  With the comments, they were unrendered (yes, I think you're right about parser being confused).

Comment: Note that it is non-standard for Markdown to add ID attributes to headers (which is what make them linkable). If "the links didn't work" this is likely why. I'm not familiar enough with remarkable to know if it supports that feature or not. In any event, it appears you found a working solution in a different library which both doesn't contain the bug and supports linking to headers.

Comment: makes sense..  and yes,  the act of articulating the question helped in finding the eventual answer!  thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - using a different [library](https://github.com/cwjohan/markdown-to-html)!

steps:

```
npm install markdown-to-html -g
markdown test.md > test.html
```

[image]

The only downside - the tool doesn't seem to convert html (comments, or images). Easy to work around this though.